# My tkinter command only runs once

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using tkinter to code a little thing which displays new images each time a button is pressed, but it won't cycle more than once.

```
 from tkinter import *
 root=Tk()
 image1=PhotoImage(file="SCIMG_Gagagigo.png")
 image2=PhotoImage(file="SCIMG_7_Coloured_Fish.png")
 image3=PhotoImage(file="SCIMG_Jerry_Beans_Man.png")
 image4=PhotoImage(file="SCIMG_Axe_Raider.png")
 image5=PhotoImage(file="SCIMG_Guardian_of_the_Throne_Room.png")
 image6=PhotoImage(file="SCIMG_Alien_Shocktrooper.png")
 image7=PhotoImage(file="SCIMG_Evilswarm_Heliotrope.png")
 image8=PhotoImage(file="SCIMG_Alexandrite_Dragon.png")
 def change():
     for a in range(4):
         array.append(array[0])
         array.pop(0)
     b1=Button(image=array[0])
     b2=Button(image=array[1])
     b3=Button(image=array[2])
     b4=Button(image=array[3])
     b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
     b2.grid(row=0,column=1)
     b3.grid(row=1,column=0)
     b4.grid(row=1,column=1)
 array=[image8,image7,image6,image5,image4,image3,image2,image1]
 b1=Button(image=array[0],command=change)
 b2=Button(image=array[1],command=change)
 b3=Button(image=array[2],command=change)
 b4=Button(image=array[3],command=change) 
 b1.grid(row=0,column=0) 
 b2.grid(row=0,column=1) 
 b3.grid(row=1,column=0) 
 b4.grid(row=1,column=1) 
 root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bad Solution

That's because no `command` is set to your new `Button`s.

```
def change():
    for a in range(4):
        array.append(array[0])
        array.pop(0)
    # Change start.
    b1=Button(image=array[0],command=change)
    b2=Button(image=array[1],command=change)
    b3=Button(image=array[2],command=change)
    b4=Button(image=array[3],command=change)
    # Change end.
    b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    b2.grid(row=0,column=1)
    b3.grid(row=1,column=0)
    b4.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

However, it is not a good fix.

#### Better Solution

Instead, configure the image:

```
def change():
    for a in range(4):
        array.append(array[0])
        array.pop(0)
    b1.configure(image=array[0])
    b2.configure(image=array[1])
    b3.configure(image=array[2])
    b4.configure(image=array[3])
```

#### Extra: Better way to rotate your image array

Replace this

```
for a in range(4):
    array.append(array[0])
    array.pop(0)
```

with

```
array = array[4:] + array[:4]
```

Comment: Great answer, all I have is a couple more flexible one-liners for shifting the array if it were to ever deviate from 4 items: `array.append(array.pop(0))` and `array = array[-1:] + array[:-1]`

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand why do you create a new button every time. You can just edit their image:

```
def change():
    for a in range(4):
        array.append(array[0])
        array.pop(0)
    b1.configure(image=array[1])
    b2.configure(image=array[2])
    b3.configure(image=array[3])
    b4.configure(image=array[4])
```

I also suggest you to use some *for* loops and arrays instead of creating PhotoImage and Button elements one by one.